# Prove: the number of simple undirected graphs with n different nodes, s.t every node has even degree is $2^\binom{n-1}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

**Prove:** the number of simple undirected graphs with n different nodes, s.t every node has even degree is $2^\binom{n-1}{2}$

**My attempt:**

I think the problem is equivalent to the number of $(n \times n)$ symetric matrices with $(0,1)$ entries, trace=0 and the sum of every row is even.

Let $F(n)$ be this number. If we have a $(n-2 \times n-2)$ such matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \dots & \dots & \dots  \\ 
\dots  & 0 & \dots &\dots  \\ 
 \dots & \dots  & 0 & \dots  \\  
 \dots & \dots  & \dots  & 0
\end{pmatrix}  $$

$$\to $$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \dots & \dots & \dots &  & \\ 
\dots  & 0 & \dots &\dots &  & \\ 
 \dots & \dots  & 0 & \dots & & \\  
 \dots & \dots  & \dots & 0 & & \\
 \dots & \dots  & \dots  & \dots  & 0 & 0 \\
 \dots & \dots  & \dots  & \dots  & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We have 2 possibilities for the $2n-4$ blank cells: either $(0,0)$ or $(1,1)$ and the right bottom square has to be only with zeros.

Therefore:

$F(n)=2^{n-2}\cdot F(n-2)$ but how do I get to $2^\binom{n-1}{2}?$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick some node. For all edges not incident at this node, you can choose independently whether they exist or not. That's $\binom{n-1}2$ binary choices. Then the constraint uniquely determines the existence of the edges incident at the selected node.

Comment: And alway the number of vertices that have odd degree is an even number because $\sum d(v)=2|E|$. This guarantees that the node that is set apart will automatically have even degree. (aside: thank you for your nice compliment.)

Comment: Thank you! Despite its complication, is my solution wrong?

Comment: @Ro168: I don't understand what you mean by "the $2n-4$ blank cells".

Comment: @joriki I mean that if you "expand" the $n-2 \times n-2$ matrix to be $n \times n$ you get 2 rows and 2 coloumns to fill. Since the matrix is symmetric you can fill only the columns. The trace is zero and the sum of every row is even so the right bottom sqaure has only zeros. That means that there are $2n-4$ places to fill.

Comment: @Ro168: I see. That approach doesn't work because you're assuming that the $(n-2)\times(n-2)$-submatrix has even row and column sums, but there's no reason why it should. You could have odd sums in that part and then $(0,1)$ or $(1,0)$ in the new part.